# Issue HTML email showing different on different platforms

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email

I am making a HTML email. Now in browser it is showing fine and how it should be. The problem appears when I sent it and check on different platforms.

How ever, in the email from transip where I host my website it shows as it should.

[I got a jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/qsbj0y9j/)

how it should be:

[image: How it should be]

Gmail: [image: Gmail]

Windows 10 mail: [image: windows 10 mail]

Here is all the code that I paste in the email.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- NAME: 1:2 COLUMN - FULL WIDTH -->
    <!--[if gte mso 15]>
        <xml>
            <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
            <o:AllowPNG/>
            <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
            </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
        </xml>
        <![endif]-->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
    <title>*|MC:SUBJECT|*</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://use.typekit.net/pyo8wnx.js">
    </script>
    <script>
    try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="bodyTable" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" id="bodyCell" valign="top">
                    <!-- BEGIN TEMPLATE // -->
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <tr class="f1f1f1">
                            <td align="center" id="templateHeader" valign="top"><!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                    <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" style="width:600px;">
                                    <tr>
                                    <td align="center" valign="top" width="600" style="width:600px;">
                                    <![endif]--></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="templateContainer" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="headerContainer" valign="top">
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnImageBlock" style="min-width:100%;" width="100%">
                                    <tbody class="mcnImageBlockOuter">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="mcnImageBlockInner" valign="top">
                                                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnImageContentContainer" style="min-width:100%;" width="100%">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class="mcnImageContent" style="padding-right: 9px; padding-left: 9px; padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0; text-align:center;" valign="top"><img align="center" alt="" class="mcnImage" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/953c1f15f29edc16163af3d3e/images/d02fceaa-c0cb-45a3-a6d5-5f56aaa98b6b.jpg" style="max-width:1360px; padding-bottom: 0; display: inline !important; vertical-align: bottom;" width="564"></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table><!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <![endif]-->
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" id="templateBody" valign="top">
                    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                    <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" style="width:600px;">
                                    <tr>
                                    <td align="center" valign="top" width="600" style="width:600px;">
                                    <![endif]-->
                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="templateContainer" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="bodyContainer" valign="top">
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnTextBlock" style="min-width:100%;" width="100%">
                                    <tbody class="mcnTextBlockOuter">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="mcnTextBlockInner" style="padding-top:0px;" valign="top">
                                                <!--[if mso]>
                <table align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width:100%;">
                <tr>
                <![endif]-->
                                                <!--[if mso]>
                <td valign="top" width="600" style="width:600px;">
                <![endif]-->
                                                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnTextContentContainer templateContainerf1-shadow" style="max-width:100%; min-width:100%;" width="100%">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding: 9px 18px 9px; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;" valign="top">
                                                                <h1><span style="font-size:18px">Beste vrienden van Funda</span></h1>
                                                                <p style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><span style="font-size:13px">Als jullie parners in print, feliciteren wij jullie met het <strong>15 jarig</strong> bestaan. Bij een verjaardag hoort natuurlijk <strong>een kado!&nbsp;</strong><br>
                                                                <br>
                                                                Met de code: <strong>funda15jaar</strong>. Krijg je korting op diverse producten. Deze producten zijn hieronder te vinden.<br>
                                                                <br>
                                                                Op nog vele mooie jaren.<br>
                                                                <br>
                                                                Veel liefs,</span><br>
                                                                <img data-file-id="29567" height="55" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/953c1f15f29edc16163af3d3e/images/42fafc76-b54e-4729-a6cf-c46d289bb936.png" style="border: 0px ; width: 200px; height: 55px; margin: 0px;" width="200"></p>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table><!--[if mso]>
                </td>
                <![endif]-->
                                                <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="templateContainer" width="100%">
                                                    <tr></tr>
                                                    <tbody class="mcnDividerBlockOuter">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class="mcnDividerBlockInner" style="min-width: 100%; padding: 9px 18px;">
                                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnDividerContent" style="min-width:100%;" width="100%">
                                                                    <tbody>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td><span></span></td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                    </tbody>
                                                                </table><!--[if mso]>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <![endif]-->
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnTextContentContainer" style="max-width:100%; min-width:100%;" width="100%">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding: 0px 18px 9px; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;" valign="top">
                                                                <h1 class="null"><strong style="color: #054973;font-size: 13px;"><span style="font-size:18px">KORTING OP</span></strong></h1>
                                                                <h1 class="null"><span style="color:#054973"><strong>JOUW FAVORIETEN</strong></span></h1>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table><!--[if mso]>
                </td>
                <![endif]-->
                                                <!--[if mso]>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <![endif]-->
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnTextBlock" style="min-width:100%;" width="100%">
                                    <tbody class="mcnTextBlockOuter">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="mcnTextBlockInner" style="padding-top:9px;" valign="top">
                                                <!--[if mso]>
                <table align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width:100%;">
                <tr>
                <![endif]-->
                                                <!--[if mso]>
                <td valign="top" width="600" style="width:600px;">
                <![endif]-->
                                                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnTextContentContainer" style="max-width:100%; min-width:100%;" width="100%">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding: 0px 18px 9px; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;" valign="top">
                                                                <h1 class="null"><span style="font-family:open sans,helvetica neue,helvetica,arial,sans-serif"><span style="font-size:13px">We geven korting op je favorieten / meest bestelde producten.</span></span></h1>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table><!--[if mso]>
                </td>
                <![endif]-->
                                                <!--[if mso]>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <![endif]-->
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnImageBlock" style="min-width:100%;" width="100%">
                                    <tbody class="mcnImageBlockOuter">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="mcnImageBlockInner" style="padding:0px" valign="top">
                                                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnImageContentContainer" style="min-width:100%;" width="100%">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class="mcnImageContent" style="padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0;" valign="top"><img align="right" alt="" class="mcnImage" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/953c1f15f29edc16163af3d3e/images/24c856f7-7794-49cd-aae2-380d93df56fd.png" style="max-width:476px; padding-bottom: 0; display: inline !important; vertical-align: bottom;" width="476"></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnImageBlock" style="min-width:100%;" width="100%">
                                    <tbody class="mcnImageBlockOuter">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="mcnImageBlockInner" style="padding:0px" valign="top">
                                                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnImageContentContainer" style="min-width:100%;" width="100%">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class="mcnImageContent" style="padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0;" valign="top"><img align="left" alt="" class="mcnImage" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/953c1f15f29edc16163af3d3e/images/597a9fb1-baad-40bf-adec-c637c4c6c1dd.png" style="max-width:476px; padding-bottom: 0; display: inline !important; vertical-align: bottom;" width="476"></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnImageBlock" style="min-width:100%;" width="100%">
                                    <tbody class="mcnImageBlockOuter">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="mcnImageBlockInner" style="padding:0px" valign="top">
                                                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnImageContentContainer" style="min-width:100%;" width="100%">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class="mcnImageContent" style="padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0;" valign="top"><img align="right" alt="" class="mcnImage" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/953c1f15f29edc16163af3d3e/images/1d0bc62d-5f79-47d2-943c-4ada62b747f7.png" style="max-width:476px; padding-bottom: 0; display: inline !important; vertical-align: bottom;" width="476"></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnDividerBlock" style="min-width:100%;" width="100%">
                                    <tbody class="mcnDividerBlockOuter">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="mcnDividerBlockInner" style="min-width: 100%; padding: 9px 18px;">
                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnDividerContent" style="min-width:100%;" width="100%">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td><span></span></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table><!--
                <td class="mcnDividerBlockInner" style="padding: 18px;">
                <hr class="mcnDividerContent" style="border-bottom-color:none; border-left-color:none; border-right-color:none; border-bottom-width:0; border-left-width:0; border-right-width:0; margin-top:0; margin-right:0; margin-bottom:0; margin-left:0;" />
-->
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnTextBlock templateContainerf1" style="min-width:100%;" width="100%">
                                    <tbody class="mcnTextBlockOuter">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="mcnTextBlockInner" style="padding-top:9px;" valign="top">
                                                <!--[if mso]>
                <table align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width:100%;">
                <tr>
                <![endif]-->
                                                <!--[if mso]>
                <td valign="top" width="600" style="width:600px;">
                <![endif]-->
                                                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnTextContentContainer" style="max-width:100%; min-width:100%;" width="100%">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding: 0px 18px 9px; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;" valign="top">
                                                                <h1 class="null"><strong style="color: #054973;font-size: 13px;"><span style="font-size:18px">PRODUCTEN</span></strong></h1>
                                                                <h1 class="null"><span style="color:#054973"><strong>OM TE PROBEREN</strong></span></h1>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table><!--[if mso]>
                </td>
                <![endif]-->
                                                <!--[if mso]>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <![endif]-->
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnTextBlock templateContainerf1" style="min-width:100%;" width="100%">
                                    <tbody class="mcnTextBlockOuter">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="mcnTextBlockInner" style="padding-top:9px;" valign="top">
                                                <!--[if mso]>
                <table align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width:100%;">
                <tr>
                <![endif]-->
                                                <!--[if mso]>
                <td valign="top" width="600" style="width:600px;">
                <![endif]-->
                                                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnTextContentContainer" style="max-width:100%; min-width:100%;" width="100%">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding: 0px 18px 9px; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;" valign="top">
                                                                <h1 class="null" style="text-align: justify;"><span style="font-family:open sans,helvetica neue,helvetica,arial,sans-serif"><span style="font-size:13px">We geven ook korting op een aantal producten die je nooit heb besteld. Zo kan je deze ook een keer proberen.&nbsp;</span></span></h1>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table><!--[if mso]>
                </td>
                <![endif]-->
                                                <!--[if mso]>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <![endif]-->
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnImageBlock templateContainerf1" style="min-width:100%;" width="100%">
                                    <tbody class="mcnImageBlockOuter">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="mcnImageBlockInner" style="padding:0px" valign="top">
                                                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnImageContentContainer" style="min-width:100%;" width="100%">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class="mcnImageContent" style="padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0;" valign="top"><img align="right" alt="" class="mcnImage" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/953c1f15f29edc16163af3d3e/images/1d228701-15a0-48dc-aca9-e1be72269baa.png" style="max-width:479px; padding-bottom: 0; display: inline !important; vertical-align: bottom;" width="479"></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnImageBlock templateContainerf1" style="min-width:100%;" width="100%">
                                    <tbody class="mcnImageBlockOuter">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="mcnImageBlockInner" style="padding:0px" valign="top">
                                                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnImageContentContainer" style="min-width:100%;" width="100%">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class="mcnImageContent" style="padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0;" valign="top"><img align="left" alt="" class="mcnImage" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/953c1f15f29edc16163af3d3e/images/a2766025-a96d-4467-9c6d-b65c6eca5292.png" style="max-width:479px; padding-bottom: 0; display: inline !important; vertical-align: bottom;" width="479"></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnImageBlock templateContainerf1" style="min-width:100%;" width="100%">
                                    <tbody class="mcnImageBlockOuter">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="mcnImageBlockInner" style="padding:0px" valign="top">
                                                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnImageContentContainer" style="min-width:100%;" width="100%">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class="mcnImageContent" style="padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0;" valign="top"><img align="right" alt="" class="mcnImage" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/953c1f15f29edc16163af3d3e/images/b03d1c00-b399-4882-b3ef-32fe5e0c354d.png" style="max-width:479px; padding-bottom: 0; display: inline !important; vertical-align: bottom;" width="479"></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnDividerBlock templateContainerf1-botshadow" style="min-width:100%;" width="100%">
                                    <tbody class="mcnDividerBlockOuter">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="mcnDividerBlockInner" style="min-width: 100%; padding: 9px 18px;">
                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnDividerContent" style="min-width:100%;" width="100%">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td><span></span></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table><!--
                <td class="mcnDividerBlockInner" style="padding: 18px;">
                <hr class="mcnDividerContent" style="border-bottom-color:none; border-left-color:none; border-right-color:none; border-bottom-width:0; border-left-width:0; border-right-width:0; margin-top:0; margin-right:0; margin-bottom:0; margin-left:0;" />
-->
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnDividerBlock templateContainerf1" style="min-width:100%;" width="100%">
                                    <tbody class="mcnDividerBlockOuter">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="mcnDividerBlockInner" style="min-width: 100%; padding: 9px 18px;">
                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnDividerContent" style="min-width:100%;" width="100%">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td><span></span></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table><!--
                <td class="mcnDividerBlockInner" style="padding: 18px;">
                <hr class="mcnDividerContent" style="border-bottom-color:none; border-left-color:none; border-right-color:none; border-bottom-width:0; border-left-width:0; border-right-width:0; margin-top:0; margin-right:0; margin-bottom:0; margin-left:0;" />
-->
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnImageBlock" style="min-width:100%;" width="100%">
                                    <tbody class="mcnImageBlockOuter">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="mcnImageBlockInner" style="padding:9px" valign="top">
                                                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnImageContentContainer" style="min-width:100%;" width="100%">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class="mcnImageContent" style="padding-right: 9px; padding-left: 9px; padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0; text-align:center;" valign="top"><img align="center" alt="" class="mcnImage" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/953c1f15f29edc16163af3d3e/images/0d3b67a9-6e0b-4227-8443-b3a820aee32f.png" style="max-width:250px; padding-bottom: 0; display: inline !important; vertical-align: bottom;" width="250"></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table><!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <![endif]-->
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" id="templateColumns" valign="top">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="templateContainer" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top">
                                <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                                <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" style="width:600px;">
                                                <tr>
                                                <td align="center" valign="top" width="300" style="width:300px;">
                                                <![endif]-->
                                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="columnWrapper" width="300">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="columnContainer" valign="top"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table><!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                                </td>
                                                <td align="center" valign="top" width="300" style="width:300px;">
                                                <![endif]-->
                                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="columnWrapper" width="300">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="columnContainer" valign="top"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table><!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                                </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                </table>
                                                <![endif]-->
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" id="templateFooter" valign="top">
                    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                    <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" style="width:600px;">
                                    <tr>
                                    <td align="center" valign="top" width="600" style="width:600px;">
                                    <![endif]-->
                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="templateContainer" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="footerContainer" valign="top"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table><!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <![endif]-->
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table><!-- // END TEMPLATE -->
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

No css due to character limit.

Comment: Follow these and your emails will be fine:

 1. All CSS should be inline (you have quiet a lot in seperate file)
  - If you are using CSS external move it into the head of the document.
 2. No Javascript

Chers

Comment: I have everything in 1 file. I figured it out tho. Jsfiddle requered me to seperare the css

Comment: So it's all working fine now